# Android: How can I save an image as a MySQL BLOB?

Tags: android, mysql

I have a problem with saving an image as a `BLOB` to MySQL. I only know the `HttpURLConnection` method, and I don't know how to make it accept `byte[]`. I can however send string to MySQL tables. But I don't know how to send Android image. I want to save it as a `BLOB`.

Comment: Dont think you can send to mysql database too. One does not directly send data from android to a database on the web. An intermediate script like a php script will receive data from android and then put that data in a database.

Comment: I have edited your question to add code markers (using `\``) where appropriate. This helps make the question more readable. Also, English only capitalizes words at the beginning of sentences and some special words called "proper nouns". Please don't capitalize other words; it can be very hard to read. Good luck!

Comment: Yes , It is Not Possible To Send Data Directly ( as `BLOB` ) To `Mysql` , Remember You Have To Use Combination Of  `Java` and `PHP`' To Achieve That Goal . Let The `Php` Translate it to `Blob`